# paired t-test... for proportions?

Tags: t-test, proportion

I did a pre-education and post-education quiz for a group of anonymous individuals. Individuals took a 2-3 question quiz, viewed an educational video, and then took another 2-3 question quiz. The quiz questions were different in the pre-quiz and post-quiz. This was repeated on 8 different occasions, each module was about a different topic. The individuals were allowed to stop participating in the process, so quite often the number of individuals that took each post-quiz was less than the number that took the pre-quiz (i.e. 10 took the pre-quiz, but only 8 took the post-quiz). Thus I can't directly compare the  number of correct answers.

Normally, I would do a McNemars if I was interested in individual questions and I could actually match the two samples. However, I am interested in the aggregate of all 8 educational modules. I am interested in comparing the amount of correct answers on the pre-quizzes versus the post-quizzes. Since the amount of questions attempted was different pre and post each time: 
(1) is it OK to do a paired t-test on the correct proportions?
(2) what test do I use if I want to look at each module individually?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with R? (Because I have an answer, but its usefulness depends on whether you use R)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with R.

Comment: Please register & merge your accounts. You can find out how in the **My Account** section of our [help]. Then you will be able to comment on your own thread.

Comment: @BrashEquilibrium : why don't you post your answer. R code and output are often self-explanatory and not very difficult to understand.

Comment: For those interested in the question who do use R, take a look at pairwise.prop.test()